# Transformer model for statement consistency / stance detection

Tags: natural-language, transformers

As an escience support programmer, I often get requests for research questions on checking a corpus for stances, or consistency with a particular statement. For example, one might wonder which news articles, tweets, etc are consistent with a statement like "Inflation is driven by fear" or with "Inflation is driven by lack of supply". This can give statistical insights in particular narratives.

Question-answering models usually fail here, since it's hard to formulate such stances as an open question that would reference a particular part in the source. Sentence similarity or cosine similarity on embedding vectors usually measure similarity rather than consistency, and might easily break on negations. Furthermore, stance detection usually is trained on just one specific stance like anti-EU or pro-choice.

I'd like to consider consistency asymmetrically, since "the flowers are red" is consistent with "the flowers are red and it rains", but not vice versa since the first statement doesn't state that it rains - although you could argue whether consistency is a valid term in this case.

Are there models or machine learning tasks that measure consistency between sentences, or consistency of a sentence (statement) with a source text?

Comment: GPT-3 should be able to do this. First, I would try it using ChatGpt which uses GPT-3.5 to see how far you can go. If ChatGpt can't do it then I would doubt if there is anything else that can do. But I am not sure if you can get an API for GPT-3 or ChatGpt to do mass analysis. However, GPT-2 or GPT-J have API's and they can do a decent job as well.

Comment: However, if chatgpt3 can't do it because of bandwidth / lack of access, what alternatives exist? GPT3 or 3.5 would have the same issue (I guess the weights are not public?), nor would it fit on any affordable machine (or cluster).